# how do i Make a web app of weather forecast

Tags: html, css

Weather Forecast App
Make a web app for users to see the current weather and the weather forecast for the next 7
days.

Requirements
An input for users to type city name
Display current weather including weather condition, temperature, humidity, wind speed, and
date and time
Visualization to display the temperature change, humidity change, and weather conditions of
each day.
Suggested Implementation
Fetch user's device position. If you're unable to get the user's position, set Delhi as the
default location.
Fetch weather data (forecast data and current weather data) of the location from weather
API
Format the data into charts
Display the chart and current weather

Comment: this reads like a school assignment copy pasted. Have you tried anything yet to solve this yourself?

Comment: wrong place to get learning what you looking for. learn code and ask what errors you get and ask here to get help.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask